# flutter firebase cloud functions and reverse engineering - dart compilation

Tags: flutter, dart, compilation, google-cloud-functions, reverse-engineering

I'm 3-season-old flutter dev now trying to compile my little app! i'm using [cloud_functions](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_functions) package, and worrying about something that might sound like a dumb idea for gurus.

Few weeks ago, i had read several articles that reverse-engineering flutter app and dart engine really explicitly, even revealing strings in the original app.

Right after reading those articles, i could've understood the reason why people interested in the security issues always say, like 'you must not include sensitive info in the plain source code since your compiled app can be reverse-engineered', and felt feared.

So i migrated all those info into firestore and locked the store with simple security rules, and here comes the main question:

Now, i'm wondering if my cloud functions's source code written in js would be compiled together when i run build commands. The directory is generally named `functions` and we can find `index.js` inside the directory, which includes really sensitive info such as the name of callable functions or core strings used in hashing methods.

If dart compilation includes `functions` folder into its process, it is possible for attackers to figure out those important info in `index.js`. IMO, it is not reasonable to do that with build methods, so i don't have to worry about it.

But i just want to make it clear through this simple question to the gurus that my `index.js` is already safe! Thanks in advance [:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Cloud Functions code are stored on Google's servers.

Here's a quote from the Cloud Functions [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions):

> Your JavaScript or TypeScript code is stored in Google's cloud and runs in a managed environment.
> There's no need to manage and scale your own servers.

And to your question about reverse engineering, Cloud Functions helps with that too.

> In many cases, developers prefer to control application logic on the
> server to avoid tampering on the client side. Also, sometimes it's not
> desirable to allow that code to be reverse engineered. Cloud Functions
> is fully insulated from the client, so you can be sure it is private
> and always does exactly what you want.
>
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions#key_capabilities

Comment: My question was quite illogical than i'd expected. Your answer is cool enough! In this case, i could even delete the whole index.js texts after `firebase deploy --only functions`, and then run the dart compilation command even if the command includes js file. Things are much clearer now! Thank you so much [: